# On Load Delegation not working with Latest Jquery 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

an iFrame is added to my page via javascript somewhere in my page, I want to be notified when it is loaded, but this doesn't work:

```
$("iframe").load(
    function () {
        alert(this.name + ": Im loaded!");
    });
```

No alert is shown
Any idea why? any idea how can we achieve this?

With Latest Jquery jQuery 3.1.1, It is not working and JS error occur inderOf is not found as in latest JS lib. it is uses a normal paramter.

Answer (score 0):

"load" method is deprecated since jQuery 1.8. 
Use "on" method instead.

```
$("iframe").on("load", function () {
    alert(this.name + ": Im loaded!");
});
```